# Not using the datetime module and even then get this, TypeError: 'DatetimeIndex'

Tags: python, datetimeindex

Hi why do I get this error and how do I correct it?

```
File "<ipython-input-451-471e59eff2c7>", line 1, in <module>
    range(6,31,7)

TypeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object is not callable
```

```
weekend_prime = []
weekends = []
weekday_prime=[]

def createWeekendData_Jan():
    for dayy in range(6,31,7): #all Sat. and Sun. of Jan.
        day_str = str(dayy)
        if(len(day_str)==1):
            day_str = '0'+day_str
        for hours in range(1,24):
            hours_str = str(hours)
            if(len(hours_str)==1):
                hours_str = ' 0'+hours_str
            else:
                hours_str = ' '+hours_str    
            weekends.append('2018-01-'+day_str+hours_str) 

createWeekendData_Jan()
print(weekends)
```

Comment: I get no error when I run your code.

Comment: I bet you have another variable called `range` somewhere

Comment: @FlyingTeller you are absolutely correct. How do I clear it? I' am using this: range = None and then I get an error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: Try setting `range=__builtin__.range` or just restart your interpreter